# TableView Cell view shadow does not coming properly in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, shadow

I have added view as a background for tableview cell and I am giving shadow for view. Here when I run tableview shadow does not coming properly, once I scroll down and up then shadow coming properly.

I have given shadow according to this answer [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxdIp.png)

Code:

```
  extension UIView {
  func dropShadow(scale: Bool = true) {
  layer.masksToBounds = false
  layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
  layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
  layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
  layer.shadowRadius = 1
  layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
  layer.shouldRasterize = true
  layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
}
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PlansTableViewCell

    cell.containerView.dropShadow()
    return cell
}
```

Before scrolling shadow coming like this:

[image]

after scrolling coming like below:

[image]

After running(before scrolling) also i need second image kind of output, Here Help me with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here

```
layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
```

`bounds` isn't correct at that time  , try
 call it from

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews()
   self.containerViewdropShadow()
}
```

**or**

```
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
cell.containerView.dropShadow()
```

Comment: can u help me to get shadow up in right side edge as well like how i am getting in left